# Newly added part of mesh won't move with Armature

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

I'm just learning how to create my own textures and materials so I can add tears and other emotions to my models face, only the tears are something I made separately and then added at the end. I tried weight painting, joining the meshes together, adding the tears to my Head vertex group with 1 weight, and parenting with automatic weights but still the tears will not move with the head or anything for that matter. Also I'm still super new to all of this.

[image: The problem]
[image: Adding the tears to the vertex group]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Armature modifier, the effect is limited to the vertex group named Armature (not sure why).

Either :

- remove the vertex group restriction in the armature modifier
- add your tears to the Armature vertex group (seems safer)

Comment: Honestly I was excited to read this because I forgot about that vertex group. It's always something simple. I have to use video tutorials for everything and the only one that worked for this model was an armature with a deform mesh- only I didnt need the deform. I ended up deleting the armature vertex group and reweight painting for the head vertex group and it finally worked! Thank you so much.